# Can you access Google Drive file revision history in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, revision-history

I wrote over filenames in Google Drive and want to link the old names listed under file revision history in the GUI (ex from picture: medium.1.jpg) to the new ones (ex from picture: 504.jpg). Is there a way to access this metadata directly in Google Colab so I can make a dictionary?

[gdrive_version_hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHk4L.jpg)